# 'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 96) near 'else'

Tags: lua

.lua:115: 'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 96) near 'else'

`local screenX = 1920
 local screenY = 1080

local retreat = 3

---

local xAxis = 0

local yAxis = 0

local onPoint = false

function nowPixel()

xNow, yNow = GetMousePosition()

yNow = screenY*yNow/65535

xNow = screenX*xNow/65535

xNow = math.floor(xNow)

yNow = math.floor(yNow)

return xNow, yNow

end

function locateMouse(distance)

xNow, yNow = nowPixel()

if xNow >= xAxis then

xDir = -1*distance

else

xDir = distance

end

if yNow >= yAxis then

yDir = 1*distance

else

yDir = distance

end

for i=0,100 do

if math.abs(xNow - xAxis) <= distance*3 or math.abs(yNow - yAxis) <= distance*3 then

break

else

MoveMouseRelative(xDir,yDir)

xNow, yNow = nowPixel()

if xNow >= xAxis then

xDir = -1*distance

else

xDir = distance

end

if yNow >= yAxis then

yDir = -1*distance

else

yDir = distance

else

xDir = distance

end`

Comment: Sorry for weird posted , any help?

Comment: If you formatted the code, you'd see the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two 'else' statements.
You may need an 'else if', otherwise the code doesn't know what to do.
Ask yourself: in which case the code must modify yDir, and xDir ?

Comment: `elseif` or you also need an extra `end`